# Why isn't this EOF javascript code appearing in the html when it is echoed?

Tags: php, eof

In this php code I use the heredoc EOF to insert some javascript:

```
        $room= <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
test;
            </script>
EOF;
```

when I try to echo $room it doesn't appear:

```
echo "<li style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"example.com\" width=\"264\" height=\"198\" alt=\"\" /> $room</li>";
```

($room doesn't appear in the html).

however if I do the same with:

```
$room= <<<EOF
test;
EOF;
```

Then the word test gets echoed in my list html element.

EDIT - to clarify, nothing appears in the source of the html when I do the first echo attempt (the list appears, but no script tags or test inside it).

Comment: I think you need to provide some more info, it should work just like you say. Did you try 'alert('test');' in stead of just test inside the javascript?

Comment: What output do you get exactly?

Comment: Did you try using a nowdoc syntax like `$room = <<<'EOF' ...`?

Comment: @David I would personally recommend the following for cleaner syntax: `echo '<li style="text-align: center;"><img src="example.com" width="264" height="198" alt="" />', $room, '</li>';` as it avoids lots of nasty escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  test;
</script>
```

basically means nothing to javascript. I'd guess you want (in a sense of outputting anything at least):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.write('test');
</script>
```

If you literally want to display the script tag, try:

```
echo '<li style="text-align: center;"><img src="example.com" width="264" height="198" alt="" />', htmlspecialchars($room), '</li>';
```

Comment: I edited my question. I'm talking about the source html, the javascript code doesn't get echoed into the source.

Comment: @David when I copy/paste your code and try it, it get's rendered perfectly. Meaning the script-tag and all.

Comment: I can assure you it doesn't appear. I just tried it again, uploaded to the server, clicked view source and is not in the li tags. I then go back, cut out the javascript tags and replace with the word 'example' and reupload and it appears in both the source and in the html output in the li tags.

Comment: @David Then you'll have to add more of the code you're using to your question. Also have a look at: http://codepad.org/qSL5Qt4t the script tag is there.

Comment: Thanks Yoshi. I am using JQTouch so perhaps that is the issue. I will investigate further and report back if I find the answer.

Comment: I found out the source of the confusion on my end. The javascript code is being passed through a post response and one is not allowed to echo javascript through an ajax response it seeems.